# Canvas drawTextOnPath and save view

Tags: android, canvas

When I draw text on canvas using

```
//mTextPaint initialized while initialize the view.
mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mTextPaint.setColor(color);

//iPath move/line to some point on onTouchEvent()
canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, iPath, 0, 0, mTextPaint);
```

[image]

When I save this view as JPEG using,

```
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(fname);
    v.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error Saving Image",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Note: `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` added while initialize the view.
[image]

Any idea on why this happens and how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Please post more source for both drawing and getting the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is default typeface. And the default typeface is `Typeface.SANS_SERIF`.

I changed to `Typeface.SERIF` by using following code and its working.

```
mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
```